# MongoDB terminate unexpectedly with an exception

Tags: mongodb, exception

This situation is repeatedly occurring in a non constant basis: MongoDB works fine during.. let's say 3 or 4 months. And then unexpectedly, it terminates, with this exception:

exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

It is being run as root.

When I start it, it works during hours, and fall down again. This happens 3 or four times, and then it returns to work during 3 months or similar, and the event repeats.

Comment: MongoDB creates and checks the mongod.lock file in its data directory to enforce the requirement that one and only one mongod can run on a set of data files at the same time. Prima facie, your problem is that mongod cannot access this file, either because another mongod instance  or program is using it  and preventing access, mongod doesn't have the right permissions, or mongod shut down unexpectedly without cleaning up the lock. Without more information, however, I can't say what the true cause is. What's going on in the logs, etc, when the problem occurs?

Comment: We entered in the stable phase, so perhaps I can tell you in about 2 months... anyway, I am running it as root and have all the permissions. Some time ago, I had to remove the lock to start. In that opportunity the lock file did not allow mongo to start. This is different, because now it starts, but when some time pass, it went down again. When there was a problem with the lock, I could not start, and was kicked inmediatly.